# Booting Win10 from a "child" VHDX failed with VHD_BOOT_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: windows-10, boot, vhd, bcdedit

during the Win10 Education installation process I create a 100GB fixed size VHDX (1) and a second VHDX (2) with the fixed sized VHDX as its parent. After attaching the fixed size VHDX (1) I successfully installed Win10.
After installation I created a second boot entry with BCDEDIT (copy {current}) and set the "child" VHDX (2) as the new device to boot.
I did the same procedure with Win7 a few years ago and it worked perfectly fine (with VHD instead of VHDX).
But when I try to reboot and select the new boot entry with the "child" VHDX I get an error message "VHD_BOOT_INITIALIZATION_FAILED".

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find a solution.
Yes, there is enough free space at the hard disk to expand the "child" VHDX during boot process and it worked with Win7 exactly that way.

What am I doing wrong? Is there no support for booting expandable VHDX?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Windows 10 on VHDX(1) before you created the child VHDX(2)? If you change VHDX(1) after creating the child, the parent-child chain will be broken. In other words you can't change<sup>A</sup> the parent after you have created child(ren) without breaking this/these child(ren).

<sup>A</sup>: Change includes even just a boot. Every boot will cause some changes on the vhdx!